# Calling C# functions from PowerShell with params keyword

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I call C# functions from PowerShell this way:

```
// C# code
public void Foo(string param1, int param2, Dictionary<string, string> param3)

# PowerShell code:  
Add-Type -Path $pathToDll

$myClass= New-Object -TypeName MyClass
$dic= New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,String]'
$dic.Add("Key1","Val1")
$dic.Add("Key2","Val2")

$myClass.Foo("Test1", 1, $dic)
```

But what if I want to call function with signature that has params in it:

```
public void Foo(string param1, int param2, params string[] param3)
```

How to call this function from powershell?

If I call it like this:

```
 $myClass.Foo("Test1", 1, "foo1", "foo2", "foo3")
```

It shows an error: Cannot find an overload for "Foo" and the argument count: "5".

Comment: To clarify the answer of Martin : your method signature tells you the method takes 3 parameters, a string, a int and an array of strings. So you'll have to either create an array of strings, store that in a variable and yse it as the 3rd parameter OR you use the way Martin described (I prefer the last one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to call it like this:

```
$myClass.Foo("Test1", 1, @("foo1", "foo2", "foo3"))
```

Basically you have to create an array for the third parameter using `@()`

Comment: That's called an explicit array.